# Apply list in nested function call in Python

Tags: python

I have two def functions that I call in a nested fashion and want to call the second in a loop. I currently can only figure out the syntax for how to call my list manually, rather than applying each member of the list.

```
#A list of the files I want to read
afiles = [['awc_mm09c.txt','integer'], ['canopy01c.txt','real'],
                 ['canopy10c.txt','real'], ['canopy33c.txt','real'],
                 ['ccapnyp6c.txt','text'], ['gclass09c.txt','text'],
                 ['nyelev09c.txt','real']]

def readfile(fn):
    conn = open(ascPath + '\\' + fn, 'r')
    # code to read data from the file
def rows(*columns):
    # code that merges data from the other files into columns
    for ID, cols in enumerate(itertools.izip(*columns)):
        yield [ID] + list(cols)
# build the SQL
strQuery = "insert into foo...;"
# run some apsw (SQLite) code
c.execute("begin")
# this works. Is there any way to avoid manually listing each item in the list?
c.executemany(strQuery, rows(readfile(afiles[0][0]),
              readfile(afiles[1][0]),
              readfile(afiles[2][0]),
              readfile(afiles[3][0]),
              readfile(afiles[4][0]),
              readfile(afiles[5][0]),
              readfile(afiles[6][0])))
c.execute("commit")

#I've tried something like the following, but to no avail:

c.executemany(strQuery, rows(
    for f in range(len(afiles_dt)):
        readfile(afiles_dt[f][0])))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
c.executemany(strQuery, rows(
    *[readfile(afiles_dt[f][0]) for f in range(len(afiles_dt))]
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the call to `rows()` by

```
rows(*(readfile(x[0]) for x in afiles))
```

Comment: my first try at this gave me this error:
"rows() argument after * must be a sequence, not generator"  
I'll keep working at it...

Comment: @Tim: The above should work at least in Python 2.5 or above. Maybe it doesn't work for even older versions of Python, in which case you could replace the pair of parens after the `*` by brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to move 'readfile(afiles[i][0])' before 'for' - because that is the way list comprehension works in python. You can update your code the following way:

```
c.executemany(strQuery, rows(*[readfile(afiles[i][0]) for i in xrange(len(afiles_dt))]))
```

OR:

```
c.executemany(strQuery, rows(*[readfile(fInfo[0]) for fInfo in afiles_dt)]))
```

Comment: Thanks! same answer as from Constaninius. I really appreciate the quick help!  I am still learning list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

How about `rows(*map(lambda (n,t):readfile(n), afiles))`